# Несколько map

Tags: java

Затратно ли для производительности хранить множество тяжелых объектов класса Player в нескольких ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Player>. К примеру есть общее кол-во игроков ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Player>, но для удобства мне надо еще обходить их по командно. И я делаю еще ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Player> team1 и ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Player> team2. В них хранятся те же игроки, но разделенные на команды. Там же хранятся только ссылки на объекты и память есть не будет, я правильно понимаю ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почти правильно. При кол-ве объектов `Player` = `N`, вы будете иметь в памяти `3*N` объектов типа `Map.Entry`, каждый из которых содержит ссылку на ваших игроков, но никак не `3*N` объектов типа `Player`.

PS: А вам точно нужен ConcurrentHashMap? Если да, то может хотя бы не во всех трех случаях?

Comment: Спасибо! А то понимал, что только ссылки хранятся, но все равно побаивался увеличивать кол-во мест хранения жирных объектов. В данном случае действительно просто HashMap, но есть места и с ConcurrentHashMap, т.к. опыта с многопоточностью немного, потому перестраховываюсь.